# Intellij can build my project but javac cannot compile/find symbol

Tags: java

I can build my project and run it with intellij but when I attempt to compile it in the terminal with `find . -name "*.java" > sources.txt; javac -sourcepath @sources.txt` it gives me errors which intellij does not detect.

I've tried refactoring (changing class names) but it obviously does not help.

```
 location: package za.co.wethinkcode.avaj.simulator
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/Flyable.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    public void registerTower(WeatherTower WeatherTower);
                              ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: interface Flyable
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/Baloon.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import za.co.wethinkcode.avaj.simulator.WeatherTower;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: package za.co.wethinkcode.avaj.simulator
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/Baloon.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    private WeatherTower weatherTower;
            ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: class Baloon
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/Baloon.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    public void registerTower(WeatherTower WeatherTower) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: class Baloon
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/JetPlane.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import za.co.wethinkcode.avaj.simulator.WeatherTower;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: package za.co.wethinkcode.avaj.simulator
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/JetPlane.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
   private WeatherTower weatherTower;
           ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: class JetPlane
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/JetPlane.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    public void registerTower(WeatherTower WeatherTower) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: class JetPlane
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/Helicopter.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import za.co.wethinkcode.avaj.simulator.WeatherTower;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: package za.co.wethinkcode.avaj.simulator
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/Helicopter.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    private WeatherTower weatherTower;
            ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: class Helicopter
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/vehicle/Helicopter.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    public void registerTower(WeatherTower WeatherTower) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: class Helicopter
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/Simulator.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    private static  WeatherTower weatherTower;
                    ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: class Simulator
src/za/co/wethinkcode/avaj/simulator/Simulator.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                weatherTower =  new WeatherTower();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class WeatherTower
  location: class Simulator
13 errors
```

I expect it to compile since it builds in intellij and does not complain about not finding the symbol.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the `-sourcepath` setting. It probably takes only the path to your source files (e.g., `src/java/`), not each individual file. You also need to use `:` as separator, not line breaks as `find` gives you.

Comment: I tried replacing line breaks with ':' it did not work. The problem is that the compiler cannot find the symbol

Comment: Nevermind @Robert I figured it out, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I was not supposed to use the -sourcepath flag. find . -name "*.java" > sources.txt; javac @sources.txt works perfectly fine. Just ommit the flag and you're good to go. Also if you do want to use sourcepath flag make sure you are inside src directory. I think -sourcepath simply prepends /src to each path found with find command.